# Spring - Filter by not empty array not working in Mongo

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb

I have the following query:

```
@CountQuery("{$and:[" +
                "{ 'active' : true }," +
                "{ 'budget' : { $ne: { $size: 0 } } }" +
            "]}")
Integer countByBudgets();
```

and this document:

```
{
  id: ...,
  active: true,
  budget: []
}
```

And the query above is returning 1 when it should return 0 as the `budget` field has no values.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, changing the following part worked:

```
"{ 'budget' : { $ne: [] } }"
```